# Getting the value from a table data to a disabled input type

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

good day, i'm kinda having a hard time figuring out how to get the value of a certain data on a table to a disabled input type tag using jquery, considering that jquery is one of my weakness sorry in advance, can you help me out with this one, my goal was whenever the user select a certain button that part no will be directly go or change the value of the input type on the left side here's my code and screenshot for more details thank you...
[image]

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-default">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Default Modal</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Part No.</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputPartNo" placeholder="Select Part No." disabled>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                 <div class="input-group">                      
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">                      
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-inputmask-alias="datetime" data-inputmask-inputformat="dd/mm/yyyy" data-mask>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.input group -->
              </div>               
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7">
                    <table id="modal" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                      <thead> 
                          <tr>
                            <th>Part No.</th>
                            <th style="width:10%">Action</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <?php
                              $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_stocks`";

                              $stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
                              if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {
                                  $stmt->execute();
                                  $result = $stmt->get_result();
                              }   

                              while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                  $ctr++;
                              ?>
                              <!-- ITEM --> 
                              <tr>                       
                              <td><?php echo $myrow["Part_no"];?></td>
                              <?php echo '<td><button id="setText'.$ctr.'">Select </button></td>'; ?>
                            </tr>                                 

                              <?php 
                                 $sr='<script> 
                                  $("#setText'.$ctr.'").click(function(event) { 
                                      $("#inputPartNo").val("'.$myrow["Part_no"].'"); 
                                  }); 
                                 </script>';
                                echo $sr;
                              }//end of loop
                          ?>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>                            
                      </tfoot>
                    </table>                 
          </div>
        </div>              
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding data attributes to each button. It is probably the easiest way.

`<button data-part="650-0017A">Select</button>`

If jQuery is your weakness just use standard javascript - add event listener to each button and update input value with its data attribute.

DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```js
var input   = document.getElementById('input'),
    buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-action');
    
buttons.forEach(function(e){
    e.addEventListener('click',function(){
        input.value = e.dataset.test;
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn-action" data-test="Lorem Ipsum 1">Action 1</button>
<button class="btn-action" data-test="Lorem Ipsum 2">Action 2</button>
<button class="btn-action" data-test="Lorem Ipsum 3">Action 3</button>
<button class="btn-action" data-test="Lorem Ipsum 4">Action 4</button>

<input id="input" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template add a class named **"setText"** `<button class="setText">Select</button>` and bind a event to get it's parenr row first td value and set it to input box as below.

```
$(".setText").click(function(event) { 
    $("#inputPartNo").val($(this).closest('tr').find("td:first").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes for the tags you wish to store on select. Then when looping over the elements table data tags use the `this` key word to get the selected values when a click event is triggered by the user.

I used static info as I have no way of showing this using dynamic values from a database. Just keep in mind, when you create the loop of table body tags that will hold your data bases info, to add the relevant classes to those tags.

```js
let $part_number = $('.part_number');
let $part_name = $('.part_name');
let $select_btn = $('.select_btn');
// here we get the values using a loop .each() 
// because the 'part number', 'part name' and 'select button' share indexing conventions
// the index can be used to find the content within the td node list that
// is not being looped. This method would not work if you did not have 
// grouped pairs of selectors that shared an index. 

// loop through the select buttons elements using it class selector and get the index
$select_btn.each(function(index){
  //use the key word this to to create a n event listener for click
  $(this).click(function(){
    // define the groups other elements values or 'textContent' for storinging the selected values
    let target_number = $part_number[index].textContent;
    let target_name = $part_name[index].textContent;
    
    // logging the values for display in the console to show it works
    console.log(target_number + ' - ' + target_name + ' has been selected')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-default">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Default Modal</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Part No.</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputPartNo" placeholder="Select Part No." disabled>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                 <div class="input-group">                      
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">                      
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-inputmask-alias="datetime" data-inputmask-inputformat="dd/mm/yyyy" data-mask>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.input group -->
              </div>               
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7">
                    <table id="modal" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                      <thead> 
                          <tr>
                            <th>Part No.</th>
                            <th style="width:10%">Action</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody id="tableBody">
                          <tr>
                            <!-- Use a selector in each of your tables data tags that will 
                                 allow you to select that data using jquery or javascript-->
                            <td class='part_number'>1234</td>
                            <td class='part_name'>widget 1</td>
                            <td>
                              <button class='select_btn'>Select</button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='part_number'>2345</td>
                            <td class='part_name'>widget 2</td>
                            <td>
                              <button class='select_btn'>Select</button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='part_number'>3456</td>
                            <td class='part_name'>widget 3</td>
                            <td>
                              <button class='select_btn'>Select</button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='part_number'>4567</td>
                            <td class='part_name'>widget 4</td>
                            <td>
                              <button class='select_btn'>Select</button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>                            
                      </tfoot>
                    </table>                 
          </div>
        </div>              
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```